# Checksum calculation changes in DPDK v.19.11?

Tags: dpdk

Since upgrading from DPDK 19.08.2 to 19.11.8, UDP Rx packets are failing the IPv4 checksum calculation.  We offload Tx checksum calculation to hardware, but on the Rx side we calculate checksum in software by calling `rte_ipv4_cksum()`.

The NIC is a Intel X722 device.

If both Tx and Rx use DPDK 19.08.2, all is ok and `rte_ipv4_cksum()` returns 0xFFFF (as I expect).

If Tx uses DPDK 19.08.2 but Rx uses 19.11.8, `rte_ipv4_cksum()` returns 0 (which we count as a failure).

Could this be a bug or am I misunderstanding the checksum calculation?

I notice there is a difference in the return statement of `rte_ipv4_cksum()` for the two versions:

In 19.0.8:

```c
static inline uint16_t
rte_ipv4_cksum(const struct rte_ipv4_hdr *ipv4_hdr)
{
    uint16_t cksum;
    cksum = rte_raw_cksum(ipv4_hdr, sizeof(struct rte_ipv4_hdr));
    return (cksum == 0xffff) ? cksum : (uint16_t)~cksum;
}
```

In 19.11.8:

```c
static inline uint16_t
rte_ipv4_cksum(const struct rte_ipv4_hdr *ipv4_hdr)
{
    uint16_t cksum;
    cksum = rte_raw_cksum(ipv4_hdr, sizeof(struct rte_ipv4_hdr));
    return (uint16_t)~cksum;
}
```

Comment: Your second code block only shows manipulating an uninitialized local variable. Are you sure that configuration is being used? Also, how are you arriving at the conclusion that "checksum offloading has stopped working"? That's not really enough information. How are you observing that something had changed?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks for your comment, in the light of which I have rewritten my question. I would appreciate any further comments you may have.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the return value of `rte_ipv4_cksum()`, for a valid checksum, has changed in DPDK 19.11.8.